# From Edge to Poloniex

Tags: exchanges

Bought bitcoin and have a balance in a exchange account at Poloniex. Is there another step I need to take or is this where the estimated value that changes is where I will be able to send this back to Edge, and change back to USD.
I guess my question is: Is this money at work for me here or do I need to do something else.
And is this deposit safe where it is or is there a layer of security that needs to be taken.
Obvious to say I'm new to this and also thank you for your help!!

Comment: Hi Don, it's not really clear what you're asking here.  Maybe explain exactly what it is you're trying to do, and also explain what is Edge.

Comment: @arubi: I guess Edge refers to a bitcoin wallet app formerly known as Airbitz.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is this money at work for me here or do I need to do something else.**

I believe Poloniex is a currency exchange. If you want to earn money simply by trading currencies back and forth, I believe you need to be an active manager of your trades.

Poloniex seem to offer [margin trading](https://www.investopedia.com/university/margin/margin1.asp) - In general I suspect this is a good way to lose money if you are new to finance.

If you don't know whether your money is at work for you then it almost certainly is not.

> **is this deposit safe where it is**

Storing money on an exchange when you are not actively trading is one of the least safe places to hold money.

The safest would be an offline wallet with well backed up keys and/or recovery seed phrase in multiple locations, with rehearsed recovery and with instructions to your heirs in case of bus.